# Allow access namespace only with certificate

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have the following scenario:

[image]

The **user red** make a http request to one of the three services in the **namespace1**. Somehow in the K8s, it should verify, if the **user red** has a valid certificate for **namespace1** to call services or not. In this case, the **user red** owns the right certificate for the **namespace1**, so it allows to call any services within the **namespace1**. The same rule is also apply for **user blue**.

But when user red try to call services in the **namespace2**, then requests should be rejected, because it does not own the right certificat for **namespace2**.

The question is, it is possible to create namespace certificate in kubernetes. For example, when I have a **certificate A**, then I can only access **namespace1** but not **namespace2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Kubernetes Services don’t offer such features. The authentication should be done in an ingress controller (e.g. nginx-ingress). You just deploy two different ones, one per namespace, with different certificate configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but it's possible to do per domain.You can use an ingress controller such as ambassador with [SNI support](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/sni/).You supply separate TLS certificates for different domains, instead of using a single TLS certificate for all domains.It is designed to be configured on a per-mapping basis, enabling application developers or service owners to individually manage how their service gets exposed over TLS.

Using SNI instead multiple ingress controller deployments is more scalable because multiple load balancers  or IPs for those ingress controllers can be avoided.

The problem with SNI is client library and browser support is limited.